# Graph Theory: Properties of even graph

Tags: graph-theory

The question is that: show that each even graph can be decomposed into edge-disjoint cycles.

What I think is: when drawing such graphs (randomly), I can produce two sets X and Y with vertices, in which X`U`Y is all the vertice and X `∩`Y is empty. But to prove in a mathematical way, how should be explained in words??

Comment: Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2542753/connected-graph-with-colored-edges/2543000#2543000

Comment: by the way, is my understanding towards "edge-disjoint cycle" correct?

Comment: I still don't understand that answers... I am frustrated on my desk =_+

Comment: What is your definition of even graph? There is more than one way to understand it.

Comment: shouldn't be all vertices in the graph have even degrees? (including 0 degree)

Answer (score 2):

If by even graph you mean all vertices have even degrees then you do as follows: start at any vertex and keep on walking, until you hit a vertex you already visited. That means you have a cycle. Remove the edges of that cycle from the graph. The remaining graph is still even. Proceed by induction.

The only thing you must notice is that "keep on walking" is well-defined, i.e. you won't get stuck, but that follows from the fact that the degree of each vertex is at least $2$. So if you entered a vertex, you can always find (some other) exit.